# how to enter only number in input box(using regex) in jquery + javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

could you please tell me how to make a input field in which user only enter numbers using regex.i am able to do using ascii values .But I need to do this using regular expression

here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/6100/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
      var BlkAccountIdV = $('#quantity').val();
var re = /[^0-9]/g;    
if ( re.test(BlkAccountIdV) ){  
    console.log("=====")
    errorflag=1;
}else {
   console.log("==tt===") 
   $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
}

     /*if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }*/
   });
});
```

Thnaks

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //called when key is pressed in textbox
    $("#quantity").keyup(function (e) {
        // if letters found flag error, display error, and remove any non-numbers
        if ($(this).val().match(/[^0-9]/g, '')) {
            $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
            console.log("=====")
            errorflag = 1;
        } else {
            console.log("==tt===")
        }
    });
    // but users can still paste values with letters into the box with right click
    // so we bind to paste event and if detected, trigger the element's keyup event
    $("#quantity").bind('paste', function (e) {
        setTimeout(function() { $(this).keyup(); }, 30);
    });
});
```

```css
#errmsg {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number :
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

### Or here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/HkEuf/6103/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){

    if(!/^[0-9]*$/.test(this.value)){

        this.value = this.value.split(/[^0-9.]/).join('');

    }

});
```

Comment: If you are refering to the first fiddle I posted, it was made to demonstrate how validation works and displays true when there are no characters in the input other than numbers (quite correctly).

Comment: @DelightedD0D I just demonstrated how to validate using regex which is what was asked. The programmer must know how to bind different events like `change` if data is pasted in or whatever else might fool the test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74498/discussion-between-kosmas-papadatos-and-delightedd0d).

Answer (score 0):

I would instead `preventDefault` the unwanted keyCode on `keydown`. That way you don't have to do any string manipulation and then replace the input value, which could look awkward, kind I'd like a flash.

```
$( 'input' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
    var numberKeys = [ /* the wanted keyCodes */];
    if ( numberKeys.indexOf( e.keyCode ) < 0 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do what ever you'd like here when the user types in a non numeric character.
    }
});
```